# Lightread not syncing with Google Reader

Tags: rss, lightread, google-reader

I have installed Lightread from the Ubuntu 12.04 repository. Initially is used for work properly, but later as the number of unread posts increased the total number of unread posts in google.com/reader was not matching with the count in the Lightread.

What could be the reason for this? I did sync in the Lightread a couple of times, but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Did you find this link, and try that? https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightread/+question/205064

Comment: Tried it out and it didn't work.